# Why does Html decode not working for &ast; &dollar;

Tags: c#, xml, decode

I have a console application to load XmlDocument , but it fail to load if the string has values like   `&ast;` `&dollar;`

Any idea how to load the xml? all responses are appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Net;   
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //string xmlStringWorking = "<xml>&copy; &uml; &Agrave; &yen; &sect;</xml>";

        string xmlStringWorking = "<xml>&ast; &dollar; &copy; &uml; &Agrave; &yen; &sect;</xml>";

        xmlStringWorking= WebUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlStringWorking);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        doc.LoadXml(xmlStringWorking);

        Console.WriteLine(xmlStringWorking);
    }
}
```

expecting special characters are [here](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IgKJn9)

Comment: I think the real question is why you have an XML document that contains entities that aren't entities in XML?

Comment: we are getting this xml from other source, not generated by our application. because of this characters we are not able to load the xml

Comment: According to Nhan Phan's comment dotnet don't support html5 decode, so the only solution is to create method like WebUtility.HtmlDecode. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

`HtmlDecode` is just intended to undo the effects of [`HtmlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2). Since `*` and `$` have no special meaning in HTML, they don't need to be encoded; therefore `HtmlEncode` would not encode them as `&ast;` and `&dollar;`; therefore `HtmlDecode` will not decode them.

Comment: Is that not possible to load xml that has &ast; &dollar;?

Comment: @NikhilKS - XML has its own rules for entities, and they're different even from the HTML ones. By default there are only 3 (IIRC) named entities in XML.

Comment: @NikhilKS - there are some resources around different entity sets available [here](https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007doc/#htmlmathml) (but note its age)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declared these entities with their values:

```
string xmlStringWorking = "<!DOCTYPE xml [<!ENTITY ast \"*\"> <!ENTITY dollar \"$\">]> <xml>&ast; &dollar; © ¨ À ¥ §</xml>";
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/reading-entity-declarations-and-entity-references-into-the-dom

Answer (score 1):

You can replace:
   * by `&#42`;
   $ by `&#36`;

```
string xmlStringWorking = "<xml>&#42; &#36; &copy; &uml; &Agrave; &yen; &sect;</xml>";
```

Comment: I'm expectiong more number of special characters, no other way?

Comment: *Why* replace perfectly valid XML encodings? There's no reason to "decode" this string. It's valid XML.

Comment: $dollar and &ast are in html5, and .NET don't support to decode it. In case you need it, you can override the decode function by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

DotNet 4.7 method `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` don't support decodeing [html5 entity set](https://www.w3.org/2003/entities/2007/htmlmathml.json).

With the help of "[AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/)" library we are able to parse html5 entities correctly

```
using System;
using System.Net;   
using System.Xml;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xmlStringWorking = "<xml>&ast; &dollar; &copy; &uml; &Agrave; &yen; &sect;</xml>";

        var parser = new HtmlParser();

        var document = parser.Parse(xmlStringWorking);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(document.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(@"body").First().InnerHtml.Replace("&nbsp;"," "));

        Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName(@"body").First().InnerHtml.Replace("&nbsp;"," "));
    }
}
```

But it failed on character `&nbsp;`

Temporary fix `.Replace("&nbsp;"," ")` is working.